# How can I create macros similar to \pnfmt, \pno, \ppno, \nopp for sections, definitions, etc.?

Tags: biblatex, macros

I would like to create macros similar to the *biblatex* macros `\pnfmt`, `\pno`, `\ppno`, `\nopp` for working with page numbers in citations, except for other modes of referencing, e.g., sections, definitions, theorems. etc. Thus, I would like to be able to use, e.g., `\secfmt`, `\secno`, `\secnos`, `\nosec` in a similar fashion for section labels. Perhaps `\nosec` and similar do not make sense in this context, however, given the default is to recognise a number as a page number.

How do I go about this? Code samples would be great, of course, but even general advice would be appreciated.

N.B., I would also like to have commands equivalent to `\ppspace` for sections, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `\pno` and friends can be found in `biblatex.sty` ([ll. 4151-4156 in v3.16](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty#L4151-L4156)).

`\pnfmt` does not necessarily relate to `page`/`pages`, it is defined as using the `postnote` format. So it does not make sense to replicate it for other pagination type (except for the analogy). Similarly, `\nopp` tells `biblatex` not to treat what follows as pages or any other sectioning type (which are implemented using the page infrastructure), so again it need not be replicated for other sectioning types (except if you want the consistency).

It should be noted that the definitions

```
\protected\def\pno{\bibstring{page}}%
\protected\def\ppno{\bibstring{pages}}%
```

for `\pno` and `\ppno` can be overwritten by `pagination`/`bookpagination` values, so `\pno` may produce "section" as well. If we don't need that for `\secno` and friends, because they will always produce "section", the definition is simple

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\newrobustcmd*{\secno}{\ERROR}
\newrobustcmd*{\ssecno}{\ERROR}

\makeatletter
\appto\blx@blxinit{%
  \protected\def\secno{\bibstring{section}}%
  \protected\def\ssecno{\bibstring{sections}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{elk,
  author     = {Anne Elk},
  title      = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year       = {1972},
  publisher  = {Monthy \& Co.},
  location   = {London},
  pagination = {paragraph},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite[see also \pno~380]{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite[then see \secno 3]{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite[see \pno~13]{elk} % produces "par" even though we used \pno

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998, see also p. 380) ipsum (Nussbaum 1978, then see §3) dolor (Elk 1972, see par. 13)]

`\ppspace` is only used by automatic formatting directives, so I don't see the need for `\ssecspace` in the context of `\pno`/`\secno` and `\ppno`/`\ssecno`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I agree on `\nosec`, though I would like to have `\secfmt` for the sake of consistency — what's the best way to do that? As for `\ssecspace`... I want spaces to be handled in the same way as with `\pno`/`\ppno`, i.e., if you write `\pno~3` and `\ppspace` is set to empty, then "p.3" is printed, but if you write `\pno3` and `\ppspace` is set to `\addnbspace`, then "p. 3" is printed, and so on. How can this be achieved for sections, etc.?

Comment: Also: is there any reason you're doing `newrobustcmd*` then redefining with `\protected\def` later? Why not just the former?

Comment: Oh, I see. because the `blx@blxinit` code doesn't run until later. But then, why bother with `blx@blxinit` at all, as opposed to simply executing the code then and there?

Comment: @Noldorin `\pnfmt` is defined as `\protected\def\pnfmt{\printtext[postnote]}`. You could issue the same definition for `\secfmt` but crucially this would not (generally) result in the section bibstring being used. `\pnfmt` actually stands for "postnote format", so this command responds to the `pagination` field, which usually means you get "pages", but absolutely need not. You could dip deep into internals and try `\newrobustcmd*{\secfmt}{\begingroup\blx@mkpageprefix{section}[\mknormrange]}` which fixes the standard postnote format, but forces section pagination. ...

Comment: @Noldorin As for `\ppspace` have a look at https://gist.github.com/moewew/fc6b4f38bf6b6102cbe27eba0e1b4360 and observe that `\ppspace` is only used when `biblatex` formats everything on its own. As soon as you go in with `\pno`, you are responsible for the spacing.

Comment: @Noldorin The `\newrobustcmd*`/`\protected\def` is mainly for consistency with how `biblatex` defines `\pno` and friends. Defining stuff in `\blx@blxinit` makes sure that a number of commands have the correct definition locally in a `biblatex` context, even if the user might have overwritten them by accident (and many `biblatex` commands simply don't make sense outside of a `biblatex` context, so they are not defined globally). `\pno` and friends are actually defined globally (unless already defined) with a dummy definition, so they don't break in `\edef` contexts. ...

Comment: ... It is true that in this case `\newrobustcmd*{\secno}{\bibstring{section}}
\newrobustcmd*{\ssecno}{\bibstring{sections}}` and no `\appto\blx@blxinit` would have been easier.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. I just posted the code I was using so far, but I think it's better to do it your way. Incidentally, is it possible to insert code before and after every postnote?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is curious, this is my solution, based on @moewe's answer to a large extent.

I ended up incorporating analogues of `\ppspace` to be consistency. It's nice to control spacing this way and always ignore the whitespace (including non-breaking space) between, e.g., `\secno` and `3` in `\secno~3` or `\secno 3`.

**Update:** Based on @moewe's comments, I'll probably remove the analogues of `\ppspace` after all.

```latex
% Define command for gobbling whitespace chars (including final non-breaking space).
\NewDocumentCommand \gobblespaces {} {
    \exp_last_unbraced:NV \peek_charcode_remove_ignore_spaces:NT \c_tilde_str {}
}

% ---- Define various bibliographic strings.

\NewBibliographyString{section}
\NewBibliographyString{sections}
\NewBibliographyString{chapter}
\NewBibliographyString{chapters}
\NewBibliographyString{figure}
\NewBibliographyString{figures}
\NewBibliographyString{footnote}
\NewBibliographyString{footnotes}
\NewBibliographyString{definition}
\NewBibliographyString{definitions}
\NewBibliographyString{proposition}
\NewBibliographyString{propositions}
\NewBibliographyString{lemma}
\NewBibliographyString{lemmas}
\NewBibliographyString{theorem}
\NewBibliographyString{theorems}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
    section = {\S},
    sections = {\S\S},
    chapter = {ch.},
    chapters = {chs.},
    figure = {fig.},
    figures = {figs.},
    footnote = {fn.},
    footnotes = {fns.},
    definition = {dfn.},
    definitions = {dfns.},
    proposition = {prop.},
    propositions = {props.},
    lemma = {lem.},
    lemmas = {lems.},
    theorem = {thm.},
    theorems = {thms.},
}

% ----

% ---- Define commands for citing various textual elements.

\NewDocumentCommand \gen_ref_cmds { m } {
    \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \item_seq { } { ##1 }
        \seq_pop:NN \item_seq \x
        \seq_pop:NN \item_seq \bibstring_singular_key
        \seq_pop:NN \item_seq \bibstring_plural_key

        \StrLeft{\x}{1}[\x_first_char]
        \exp_args:NNc \tl_set:Nn \xxspace { \x_first_char \x space }
        \exp_args:NNc \tl_set:Nn \xno { \x no }
        \exp_args:NNc \tl_set:Nn \xxno { \x_first_char \x no }

        \exp_args:NV \NewDocumentCommand \xxspace {} {
            \addnbspace
        }
        \exp_args:NV \NewDocumentCommand \xno {} { \ERROR }
        \exp_args:NV \NewDocumentCommand \xxno {} { \ERROR }

        \exp_args:NNe \appto \blx@blxinit {
            \RenewDocumentCommand \xno {} {
                \exp_not:N \bibstring {\bibstring_singular_key}
                \xxspace
                \exp_not:N \gobblespaces
            }
            \RenewDocumentCommand \xxno {} {
                \exp_not:N \bibstring {\bibstring_plural_key}
                \xxspace
                \exp_not:N \gobblespaces
            }
        }
    }
}

\gen_ref_cmds {
    { {sec} {section} {sections} }
    { {ch} {chapter} {chapters} }
    { {fig} {figure} {figures} }
    { {fn} {footnote} {footnotes} }
    % { {eq} {equation} {equations} }
    { {dfn} {definition} {definitions} }
    { {prop} {proposition} {propositions} }
    { {lem} {lemma} {lemmas} }
    { {thm} {theorem} {theorems} }
}

% ----

% ---- Configure spaces within citations.

\RenewDocumentCommand \ssecspace {} {}
\RenewDocumentCommand \ppspace {} { \addnbspace }

% ----
```